# How would I make it so that an individual person is the only one who can run a command with a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a debug command for my bot that prints all of the current stacks that are running. Problem is it also prints my bot token. Rather than making it so it doesnt print my token, i'd rather make it so the debug command can only be ran by me.

my program:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import command
import youtube_dl
import traceback
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [['Song', 'Queued by', 'Duration']]

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello!", ctx.author)
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Join a voice channel please.")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Music is paused.")

    @commands.command()
    async def online(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("The bot is online.")

    @commands.command()
    async def debug(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("You are: ")
        await ctx.send(ctx.author)
        await ctx.send("You are in the channel:")
        if ctx.author.voice:
            await ctx.send(ctx.author.voice.channel)
        else:
            await ctx.send("None")
        await ctx.send("Stack: ")
        for line in traceback.format_stack():
            await ctx.send(line.strip())

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Music has been resumed.")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(tabulate(table, headers='firstrow'))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example `return` when the user's id that used the command is not yours:

```py
@commands.command()
async def debug(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.id != "your id":
        return

    # The rest of your debug command
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!